# install font on android device by programming

Tags: android, android-fonts

I want to add some fonts on my android device. I know it must be rooted to install fonts. But some devices like galaxies (mine is Galaxy S II) support fonts without being root. I mean what's the way to add fonts on non-rooted devices (if supported)?
Is it just copying that font in the font folder or something?
thank you in advance!

I don't want to use a font in an application and just change type of a text view or something. I want to change font of my android system. For example the font of setting menu and other places of that device.

Comment: Any solution for this? i think i made it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

You you can, 
u can't define font into **xml** layouts. You need to use it dynamically each time. Check [this tutorial](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/) for instance.

In case link is dead, here is a sum up of the stuff :

Get a font file like **times.ttf**

put it in your asset folder, inside a "fonts" folder
,Get a reference of `TextView`(Ui Element) with something like that:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myCustomTVFont);
```

Grab you font from the asset folder:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/times.ttf");
```

Make your TextView look great:

```
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: I don't want to use a font in an application and just change type of a text view or something. I want to change font of my android system. For example the font of setting menu and other places of that device.

Comment: if u  want to change font of my android system. then u have to first make android device root for more refer this solution http://www.droid-now.com/2013/03/why-root-advantages-disadvantages/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set typeface each time. You can create a custom TextView

```
public class CustomFontTypeTextView extends TextView {


    public CustomFontTypeTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }


    public CustomFontTypeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Your TypeFce");
            setTypeface(font);
        }
    }
}
```